# Disable text from keyboard suggestions on EditText

Tags: android

To prevent an EditText from receiving content from the clipboard, I disable the long click and text selectable, plus cleared the action mode menu:

```
isLongClickable = false
customInsertionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep receiving clipboard suggestions that when selected are pasted to my EditText. How can I disable this or simply ignore this pasted content?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `inputType` to `textNoSuggestions`.

Like this, in your xml file:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: I already set inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
But It don't work